# Cant get x-axis to appear with flot line graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="center-block" style="width: 75%; margin-top: -50px;" >
        <div class="chart-edge">
            <div id="line-chart" class="flot-chart"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        var d1 = [[1, 300], [2, 600], [3, 550], [4, 400], [5, 300]];

        var options = {

            xaxis: {
                show: true,
                position: "bottom",
                min: 0,
                max: 6,
                mode: null,
                tickSize: 1,
                axisLabel: 'Month',
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                // axisLabelPadding: 5
            },
            yaxis: {
                show: true,
                axisLabel: 'Temperature (C)',
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                axisLabelPadding: 5
            },
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 0.7 }, { opacity: 0.1}] }
                },
                points:{
                    show: true,
                    radius: 3
                }
            },
             grid: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                labelMargin:10,
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                mouseActiveRadius:6,

            },
            colors: ["#FF7070", "#0022FF"],
            legend: {
                show: true
            },
        };

        if ($("#line-chart")[0]) {
            $.plot($("#line-chart"), [d1], options);
        }   

    });
</script>
```

The graph is appearing but without an x-axis.  Here is the graph that appears:

[image: Graph made by Flot]

How do I get the x axis to appear?

Comment: Create a fiddle please.

Comment: Is there a version of flot that can be accessed at a url?  I don't have flot in any production environment to link to the fiddle.

Comment: It seems like it work fine without changing anything take a look **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/A24Vt/201/)**.

Comment: Does it look ok if you remove the `margin-top: -50px;`?